# Guest Site User - INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Tags: community, visual-workflow

Getting a confusing insufficient access on cross reference id when trying to insert junction records as a community guest user. I've created a 'registration' flow that collects contact information, creates a contact record, and then creates 'volunteer group membership' records for that contact based on previous selections in the flow.

The contact creation is successful, but I am not able to insert Volunteer Group Member records after the fact.

```
SUBFLOW: Create_Vol_Group_Memberships
Enter flow Create_Volunteer_Group_Memberships version 2.
Inputs:
chosenVolunteerGroups = {!Group_Interest} (Pacific Crest Trail Association; PCTA: Can do Crew)
conId = {!Create_Contact_Record} (0036s000001X0D8AAK)
DECISION: Inputs_not_blank
Outcome executed: Continue
Outcome conditions:
1. {!conId} (0036s000001X0D8AAK) Is null false

{!newGroupMembership.Contact__c} = "0036s000001X0D8AAK"
{!newGroupMembership.Contact__c} = "0036s000001X0D8AAK"
{!newGroupMembership.Volunteer_Group__c} = "a1i6s000000Cc6xAAC"
{!newGroupMembership.Role__c} = "Volunteer"
ASSIGNMENT: Add_Membership_to_List
{!membershipsToCreate} Add {!newGroupMembership}
Result
{!membershipsToCreate} = "[Volunteer_Group_Member__c (No ID),Volunteer_Group_Member__c (No ID)]"
LOOP: Loop_though_all_groups
End Loop.
DECISION: Groups_to_Create
Outcome executed: Yes
Outcome conditions:
{!membershipsToCreate} ([Volunteer_Group_Member__c (No ID),Volunteer_Group_Member__c (No ID)]) Is null false
FAST CREATE: Insert_Memberships
Create Volunteer_Group_Member__c records using the values that are stored in {!membershipsToCreate}.
Variable Values
[Volunteer_Group__c=a1i6s000000Cc02AAC,Role__c=Volunteer,Contact__c=0036s000001X0D8AAK]
[Volunteer_Group__c=a1i6s000000Cc6xAAC,Role__c=Volunteer,Contact__c=0036s000001X0D8AAK]
Result
Failed to create records.

Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: 0036s000001X0D8. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.---This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: 0036s000001X0D8. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.
Salesforce Error ID: 1731177766-28685 (-949224236)
```

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://www.infallibletechie.com/2012/12/insufficient-access-rights-on-cross.html). There is a troubleshooting steps.

Comment: I have, but am not sure how much of this applies to a site guest user. I've tried creating sharing rules, enabling CRUD and still am running into the error

Comment: For reference, the guest user IS able to create a contact record with no sharing or CRUD access, and I'm unsure why I'm not able to do so for a custom object.